# Using Moq for a repository interface method?

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following method on my repository interface:

```
IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class;
```

I have a class I'm going to act on in a unit test with the following constructor:

```
public MyClass(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
```

On `IUnitOfWork` Interface there is an exposed Repository property:

```
Repository Repository { get; }
```

So I'm trying to unit test the `MyClass.DoSomething()` method like so:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{

    accounts = new List<Account>()
    {
        new Account()
            {
               Id = 123
            }
    };
}
```

Next I have the unit test `Arrange` section which is failing:

```
//Arrange
var repositoryMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Repository.GetQuery<Account>(y => y.Id == 123))
                           .Returns(accounts.AsQueryable()); //This setup always fails
var myClass = new MyClass(repositoryMock.Object); //don't even get here
```

The exception I get is:

> **System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Repository.GetQuery(y =>
>   y.Id == 123)**

I've tried other variations of the `Setup` on the mock:

```
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Repository.GetQuery<Account>()).Returns((Account a) => accounts.AsQueryable().Where(z => z.Id == 123));
```

and

```
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Repository.GetQuery<Account>(y => y.Id == 123)).Returns((Account a) => accounts.AsQueryable().Where(z => z == a));
```

But to no success; I get the identical exception each time. They always throw the same exception when I run the unit test. Since I am using an Interface to be mocked, why am I getting this exception and how do I do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Repository property you have shown is not of an interface type. It's some concrete class. And as the error message tells you, you cannot define expectations on non virtual methods. So what you should do instead is to work with an abstraction if you want to be able to mock it:

```
IRepository Repository { get; }
```

Comment: This *technically* is the answer to my original post to solve the error I was getting. However even after applying this, my original query and syntax was incorrect and the answer by @HuseinRoncevic solved another problem I would have had regardless. Thanks to both, marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your current setup try this:

```
//Arrange
var repositoryMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Repository.GetQuery<Account>(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>());
    .Returns(accounts.AsQueryable()); // This should not fail any more
var myClass = new MyClass(repositoryMock.Object);
```

In reality, you do not need to pass any concrete lambda because you are returning your list either way.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but when I call `myClass.DoSomething` that uses the injected mockd' repository, the query called internally yields no results. There is no error, just nothing is returned. I've looked at the code 20x over and it all seems to make sense: "here is a mockd' instance of the repository that will return the list `accounts` upon the `Repository.GetQuery<Account>` being called." So why would a simple query not yield any results? (good point to about not needing to pass concrete lambda - yes I always want entire list returned).

Comment: Nevermind - figured this out. I had *2* implementations of `GetQuery` in the repository. One takes an expression, the other just an entity. The overload I was testing was *actually* the one that just took the entity. I was composing the query on the returned `IQuerable` results to *then* apply the additional lambda expression filtering. Therefore your code would work if my query had been supplying the expression as part of the original call to `GetQuery`. I didn't understand all of this at the time of my OP. Thanks for your help.